# Android Room: Converting lists of custom objects nested inside top-level entity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am trying to create a database in Android Room and I have been unsuccessful in squashing the following error:
`e: [ksp] Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type). - kotlin.collections.List`

I know this is being caused by `timerIntervals: List<Interval>` in my Timer entity, but I have no idea how to fix it. I have gone through the docs, and numerous SO answers to similar issues but none have worked.

Entities and sub-models

```kotlin
@Entity
data class Timer(
    ...
    @Embedded var timerIntervals: List<Interval>,
    ...
) {
    constructor() : this(
        ...
        timerIntervals = listOf(Interval()),
        ...
    )
}

data class Interval(
    val intervalName: String,
    val intervalDuration: Duration,
) {
    constructor() : this("", Duration())
}

data class Duration(
    val hours: Int,
    val minutes: Int,
    val seconds: Int,
) {
    constructor() : this(0, 0, 0)
}
```

TimerDao

```kotlin
@Dao
interface TimerDao {
    @Insert suspend fun createTimer(timer: Timer)
    @Delete suspend fun deleteTimer(timer: Timer)
    @Update suspend fun updateTimer(timer: Timer)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM timers WHERE userId = :key")
    fun getTimerByUser(key: String): Flow<List<Timer>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM timers WHERE timerId = :key")
    fun getTimerByKey(key: Int): Flow<Timer>
}
```

Database

```kotlin
@Database(
    entities = [User::class, Timer::class],
    version = 1
)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class SyncFitDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract val userDao: UserDao
    abstract val timerDao: TimerDao
}
```

Converter Attempts

```kotlin
class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromIntervalList(intervals: List<Interval>): String {
        val gson = Gson()
        val type = object : TypeToken<List<Interval>>() {}.type
        return gson.toJson(intervals, type)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toIntervalList(intervals: String): List<Interval> {
        val gson = Gson()
        val type = object : TypeToken<List<Interval>>() {}.type
        return gson.fromJson(intervals, type)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromTimer(timer: Timer): String {
        val gson = Gson()
        val type = object : TypeToken<Timer>() {}.type
        return gson.toJson(timer, type)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toTimer(timer: String): Timer {
        val gson = Gson()
        val type = object : TypeToken<Timer>() {}.type
        return gson.fromJson(timer, type)
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding a default value for all the attributes of the entity classes in the primary constructor itself, not in the secondary constructor

Comment: @zaidkhan the error is still there